# Getting image patches shape as (81, 256) and not (1,81,256)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have made image patches from an image classifier. When I print it's shape it is (81, 256) which means 81 patches each with size of 256. but it lost the information of the image like these 81 patches belong to a specific image. I want to get it's shape like (1, 81, 256) so if I have batch of 20 images then it will show (20, 81, 256).

```
class Patches(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, patch_size):
   super(Patches, self).__init__()
   self.patch_size = patch_size

  def call(self, images):
   batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
   patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
    images=images,
    sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
    strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
    rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding="VALID",
   )
   patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
   patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
   return patches
```

Model code

```
xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)

for layer in xception.layers:
    layer.trainable = trainable

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(300, 300, 3), name="image_input")
patch_size = 72

print("inputs shape is ", inputs.shape)

xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(inputs)
print("xception shape is", xception_input.shape)
patches = Patches(patch_size)(xception_input)

print("patches shape is", patches.shape)

patches = tf.reshape(patches, [-1, 32, 32, 3])

print("patches shape is", patches.shape)

embeddings = xception(patches)

output = embeddings(
    embeddings, projection_layers, dims, dropout_rate
)

print("output shape is ", output.shape)
return keras.Model(inputs, output)
```

Ouput

```
inputs shape is  (None, 300, 300, 3)
xception shape is (None, 300, 300, 3)
patches shape is (None, None, 15552)
patches shape is (None, 32, 32, 3)

output shape is (81, 256)
```

Below code converts each patch to size of 256 lenght

```
def embeddings(
embeddings, projection_layers, dims, dropout_rate
):
projected_embeddings = layers.Dense(units=projection_dims)(embeddings)
for _ in range(num_projection_layers):
    x = tf.nn.gelu(projected_embeddings)
    x = layers.Dense(projection_dims)(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    x = layers.Add()([projected_embeddings, x])
    projected_embeddings = layers.LayerNormalization()(x)
return projected_embeddings
```

Comment: how do you get the last `print` statement?  you haven't really explained where the number 81 is coming from

Comment: 81 are the number of patches generated from a single image of size (300, 300, 3).

Comment: Also include the code up to where you get that last print statement, i'm still not clear how you generate 81 patches from your image.

Comment: It is the output shape, when I print the output it is (81, 256).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of adding a dimension to your numpy array, you can use [`expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((81, 256))  # example array of same shape like yours
print("Old shape: {}".format(array.shape))

new_array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
print("New shape: {}".format(new_array.shape))
```

The output:

```
Old shape: (81, 256)
New shape: (1, 81, 256)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but I don't to do it by expand_dim, is there any way to change my image model code so that I can get the 3d shape?